# NordVPN in Ubuntu Touch OTA 11

Tags: ubuntu-touch, vpn, openvpn

Can someone explain how to set up NordVPN on Ubuntu Touch version OTA 11?
I found this tutorial for the Ubuntu desktop: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very good question, I'm trying since OTA10 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/754878/how-to-setup-openvpn-provided-with-ota10-on-ubuntu-touch/772699 , now on OTA11 with VPN in setting menu with error message "The VPN connection to "au1.nordvpn.com" failed because there was not valid VP.....I do import valid CA certificate and TLS key...

Comment: @Pavel Perina I tested the above configuration but it does not. I've updated the question